# Get image uri from Source

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

How do I get the image url? My xaml is:

```
<toolkit:HubTile Name="Demo" Title="Demo" Source="demo\0.png"  Margin="15" Tap="Demo_Tap"/>
```

and in c# I try to get the url from the sender (because I have a lot of entry's in the same tap)
my c# so far

```
((Microsoft.Phone.Controls.HubTile)(sender)).Source
```

and I get errors

what I need rests inside

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage m_string;
```

but how do I access that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Source` is a `BitmapImage` you can just cast the sender source as `BitmapImage`

```
(((Microsoft.Phone.Controls.HubTile)(sender)).Source as BitmapImage).UriSource.OriginalString
```

Comment: nop, error... Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' to 'System.Uri'

Answer (score 0):

**Source**

Source is a dependency property of type ImageSource. It gets or sets the image source of the HubTile control.

Are you casting to an ImageSource when getting the value?  Also, it would help if you displayed the error message.

**Update**

Per your update, casting to a BitmapImage and getting the UriSource would probably get you what you want:

```
(BitmapImage).UriSource
```

Comment: the error is : cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' to 'string'